# Failure in kubernetes working deployment files , after cluster upgradation from 1.11 to 1.14.6, being deployed via circleCI

Tags: azure, kubernetes, circleci, azure-aks

I am using circleCI for deployments, with AKS version 1.11 , the pipelines were working fine but after the AKS upgradation to 1.14.6, failure is seen while applying the deployment and service object files.

I deployed manually at kubernetes cluster, there didn't appear any error but while deploying through circleCI, I am getting following kind of errors while using version 2 of circleCI

```
error: SchemaError(io.k8s.api.extensions.v1beta1.DeploymentRollback): 
invalid object doesn't have additional properties
```

or the other kind of error appears like -

```
error: SchemaError(io.k8s.api.core.v1.StorageOSVolumeSource): invalid 
object doesn't have additional properties
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely that the version of kubectl used in CircleCI isn't supported by 1.14.6. Note that kubectl version must be either `1.n`, `1.(n+1)` or `1.(n-1)` where n is the minor version of the cluster. In this case your kubectl must be at least 1.13.x or at most 1.15.x

Checkout [Kubernetes version and version skew support policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/#kubelet-1) for more details.

Comment: Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:36:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}


Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.6", GitCommit:"96fac5cd13a5dc064f7d9f4f23030a6aeface6cc", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-19T11:05:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: This is something which AKS did on its own during upgradation, as this is a managed service. And if I look to do deployments manually then they are working fine. Just issue is appearing with circleCI only

Comment: AKS will upgrade kubectl on the nodes but will not upgrade CircleCI's kubectl client. You will have to upgrade either the image or the version of kubectl running in the pipeline

Comment: OKay, I shall try this and then I will acknowledge you