# Gitlab CI/CD with Kubernetes 1.16: Does my production job fail due to the Kubernetes version?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

We are using Gitlab's CI/CD Auto DevOps on gitlab.com with a connected Kubernetes cluster. Until recently, we ran on Azure, but have now decided to switch over to digitalocean. The build / deploy pipeline used to run fine on Azure, but when I run it now on our fresh cluster, I’m getting this error during the "production" job:

```
$ auto-deploy deploy
secret/production-secret replaced
Deploying new release...
Release "production" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: validation failed: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind 
"Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

After doing some googling, I found this release announcement for Kubernetes 1.16, which states that the Deployment resource has been moved up from extensions/v1beta1 to (eventually) apps/v1, and - more importantly - has been dropped from extensions/*:

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/09/18/kubernetes-1-16-release-announcement/

The Kubernetes version used on digitalocean is indeed 1.16.2. I do not recall the version we used on Azure, but judging from the article’s date, the 1.16 release is somewhat recent (September 2019).

As far as I can tell, the deployment algorithm is implemented inside Gitlab's "auto-deploy" image, specifically [this script](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-deploy-image/blob/master/src/bin/auto-deploy), but I fail to see where I can adapt the specific `kubectl` commands being executed.

My question is this: Am I right in assuming that this issue is caused by Gitlab’s CI/CD using a pre-1.16 notation to automatically create Deployments on Kubernetes clusters? If so, how can I adapt the deployment script to use the apps/v1 scope?

Comment: what is the version of kubectl in the CI tool ?

Comment: @TusharMahajan if my interpretation of [this file](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-deploy-image/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) is correct, they're using 1.13.12

Comment: how do you even get to the point that deployment pipeline appears?? I've added DO cluster and autodevops just build and test image, but no deployment pipeline appears :( I've tried a lot of stuff already, still doesn't work!

Comment: @holms that problem probably deserves a new SO question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, Gitlab Auto DevOps indeed does not support Kubernetes 1.16 as of yet. They're [working on it](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/32720).

See also [the issue I opened on gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-deploy-image/issues/18).

I assume it's possible to fork the helm chart project and build your own version, but I'm not willing to go to those lengths.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error while doing it with circleCI, then found that the kubectl version was 1.13 against the kubernetes version of 1.15.4 , so refer to this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58268643/failure-in-kubernetes-working-deployment-files-after-cluster-upgradation-from) and try placing the kubectl version in gitlab, same as the one your current kubernetes cluster shows.

you can do

```
kubectl version
```

to get the client and server versions, just match the gitlab kubectl with the updated one

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm afraid it doesn't really help me: To get to use a more recent version of kubectl in Gitlab's CI/CD environment, I'd have to fork, modify and rebuild [this project](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-deploy-image) and then re-wire our project's auto build config to that image. This is not ideal because it means our project would no longer be using gitlab's standard workflow, and would require a lot more maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'apps/v1' for 'apiVersion', 'extensions/v1beta1' has deprecated Deployment for a few versions now.

Comment: Yes, I had gathered as much from the Kubernetes release announcement. However, I do not write the Kubernetes config files myself - it's all done automatically by Github CI/CD, which is the issue.

Comment: You can build your own deployment or if that's too much work then you have to wait until they fix it there's no that way

Answer (score 0):

> As it turns out, Gitlab Auto DevOps indeed does not support Kubernetes 1.16 as of yet.

That might change with [GitLab 13.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/10/22/gitlab-13-5-released/#incremental-rollout-via-autodevops-is-compatible-with-kubernetes-116) (October 2020)

> ### Incremental rollout via AutoDevOps is compatible with Kubernetes 1.16
>
> Clusters in GKE were automatically upgraded to Kubernetes v1.16 on October 6th, 2020. We
> updated [Auto DevOps](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/) to support this version
> for incremental rollouts to continue working as expected. This upgrade affects users who
> continuously deploy to production using timed incremental rollout, and those who automatically
> deploy to staging but manually deploy to production.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/209045).

And that comes with, still with [GitLab 13.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/10/22/gitlab-13-5-released/#upgrade-auto-devops-to-helm-3):

> ### Upgrade Auto DevOps to Helm 3
>
> Auto DevOps aims to bring outstanding ease of use and security best practices to its users, out of the box. Until now, Auto DevOps in Kubernetes environments required Helm v2 to be installed on the cluster. This presented a security risk given Tiller’s root access rights. With the introduction of Helm v3, Tiller is no longer a requirement.
>
> **The current GitLab version finally supports Helm v3** so you can rest assured you’re getting the latest and great functionality and security updates. In the case of a GitLab Managed Cluster, you can upgrade your Helm installation by following our documentation. Note that Helm 2 support is expected to end around November 2020.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/installation/) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/29038).

As I [mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67657536/6309) (May 2021), Helm V2 will be *not* supported starting GitLab 14.0 (June 2021).