# How to install gitlab-runner in Azure Kubernetes Service?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, gitlab-ci-runner, azure-aks

I'm trying to install Gitlab Runner inside my cluster in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS), but I have 2 errors:

1. Helm Tiller doesn't appear in the application list of Gitlab CI:
   Most of tutorials tell that it has to be installed, but today it is not even proposed as you can see here:
   [image]
2. When I install gitlab-runner from this list, I have a message error like
   "Something went wrong while installing Gitlab Runner
   Operation failed. Check pod logs for install-runner for more details"
   So when I check the logs, I have this:
   [image]

The 2 last lines there is an error, some answers tell that I need to change the repo with Helm command, so I do that from the Azure CLI bash in the portal, but I still have the same error, I execute the code like this :

```
helm repo rm stable
helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable
```

And then I update, do I need to give more arguments in commands?

Comment: helm tiller is depricated https://helm.sh/blog/helm-v2-deprecation-timeline/. Use helm v3

Answer (score 1):

GitLab 13.12 (May 2021) does clearly mention:

> ### [Helm v2 support](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/05/22/gitlab-13-12-released/#helm-v2-support)

> Helm v2 was [officially deprecated](https://helm.sh/blog/helm-v2-deprecation-timeline/) in November of 2020, with the `stable` repository being [de-listed from the Helm Hub shortly thereafter](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/11/09/ensure-auto-devops-work-after-helm-stable-repo/).
>
> **With the release of GitLab 14.0 (June 2021), which will include the 5.0 release of the [GitLab Helm chart](https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/), Helm v2 will no longer be supported.**
>
> Users of the chart should [upgrade to Helm v3](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/v2_v3_migration/) to deploy GitLab 14.0 and above.

So that is why Helm Tiller doesn't appear in the application list of Gitlab CI.